# Android Dev in Java using VS Code Extension (Adelphes)- Need Tutorial

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-code

I'm looking to use VS Code instead of Android Studio for quick build & development. I have read about the awesomeness of this extension, and so I installed it, but I wasn't able to follow through the steps in the [GitHub page](https://github.com/adelphes/android-dev-ext).
It made no sense to me because of the little knowledge I have. Is there a video/tutorial out there, or can someone please explain how to use it?

I tried to ask this question on the Reddit Android forum and they asked me to ask this question here and took my question down:

> Your post from androiddev was removed because of: 'Rule 2: No "help me" posts
>   Soliciting general discussion about
>   architecture, performance optimizations, or design is fine. Asking for
>   technical help with your specific problem is not and you must redirect
>   them to StackOverflow or the Weekly Questions Thread stickied to the
>   subreddit. This also includes “which/what/how should I learn/do”
>   threads.

Please let me know if there's a better place to ask this question.